# Spresense Arduino IDE、アナログマイク入力のACカップリングをDCカップリングにしたい

Tags: spresense

Spresense Arduino IDEでWav録音を検討しています。
（音楽用での利用ではなく、アナログ電位の記録）
アナログマイク入力(MICA,MICB,MICC,MICD)の全4chを利用します。

このとき、アナログ入力はACカップリングとなっているとガイドには記載がありました。
直流電位も記録したいので、DCカップリングにしたいと考えています。

ガイドで探しましたが、見つけきれませんでした。

DCカップリングにするには、どこを変更すれば良いでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spresenseのプロセッサの[コンパニオンチップのデータシート](https://www.sony-semicon.com/files/62/pdf/p-28_CXD5247GF_technical_manual_rev1p3.pdf)を見ると、さらっと次のような記述があります。

**"The input systems include a ΔΣADC that supports four analog MIC inputs"**

[こちらの資料](https://www.rohm.co.jp/electronics-basics/ad-converters/ad_what6)にあるように、ΔΣADCは微分値を積算して値を取得する方式なので、直流成分を扱うことができません。この方式は、多くのDSPやマイク入力付きマイコンで採用されているので、他のチップでも事情は変わらないと思います。

Spresenseで直流成分を取得するには、マイク入力ではない方のADC（A0-A6）を使うしかないと思います。

Comment: JP14を短絡して試していましたが、うまくいっていませんでした。マイク入力ではない方について考えたいと思います。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

ACカップリングにしてるってのは、ソフトウエアの話ではなく、ハードウエア上の話です。
はんだごて持ってきて、Spresense 基板のパターンを切るなりして入力回路を修正する必要があります

Comment: ありがとうございます。拡張ボードのアナログマイク用2.54mmピンヘッダの近くに、コンデンサか何かが有って、それを外すのだと思うのですが、その位置は、どこになりますでしょうか。

Comment: それはその基板の回路図を見て、そこから判断しましょう。私はそいつは持ってません。んで、おそらく既存の回路がそのまま使える、って話ではないと思われますが。

Comment: ありがとうございます。検討してみます。

Comment: JP14（デジタル入力時ショート）に並列で入っているC37,C38,C40,C41が対応していることが判りました。ありがとうございました。